# When querying Flow blockchain I get a CORS error

Tags: onflow-cadence

When executing a query through javascript I get a CORS error:

Access to fetch at 'http://access.mainnet.nodes.onflow.org:9000/v1/scripts?block_height=sealed' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

This error happens when querying from testnet and mainnet.
Also happens from localhost or from a site running in Vercel.

The rpcs I tried:
`https://access-testnet.onflow.org/`
`http://access.devnet.nodes.onflow.org:9000/`
`http://flow-testnet.g.alchemy.com:443/`
(also tried their mainnet counterparts)

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem using these rpcs:

- https://rest-testnet.onflow.org/
- https://rest-mainnet.onflow.org/